# Crop circles appeared on Android emulator and it hanged

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, android-virtual-device

The following "crop circles" appeared on my Android emulator AVD

[image]

and it hanged. What is this, how to recover from this and disable this?

Probably it is a reaction of keyboard switch and/or `shift` button press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These circles are the `multi touch` functionality that Android Emulator AVD provides. Are shown when the `Ctrl` key is pushed. If these circles are activated without holding `Ctrl` key then you can deactivate them by going to `Setting->General->send keyboard shortcuts`  and change it from `Emulator Controls` to `Virtual Device`

Answer (score 0):

One small detail people overlooked. You have to run the Emulator in standalone mode, and not linked to the tool window. When you run it Standalone the Multi-Touch gesture works as described...